# can't read from firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've firebase database implemented, I want to parse all the json data which is added by me in realtime database. code below represent how I try to parse it, but the error is always the same it's: `Failed to parse conversations` which is `snapshot.value` error as you can see in the code

```swift
    public func getConversation(with email: String, completion: @escaping(Result<Conversation, Error>) -> Void) {
        database.child("\(email)/conversations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("Failed to parse snapshot value")
                let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to parse conversations"])
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
            let conversations: [Conversation] = value.compactMap { dictionary in
                guard let conversationId = dictionary["id"] as? String else {
                    print("Failed to parse conversation ID")
                    return nil
                }

                guard let latestMessage = dictionary["latest_message"] as? [String: Any],
                      let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                      let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                      let isRead = latestMessage["is_read"] as? Int else {
                    print("Failed to parse latest message")
                    return nil
                }

                guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                      let otherUserEmail = dictionary["other_user_email"] as? String else {
                    print("Failed to parse name or other user email")
                    return nil
                }

                let latestMessageObject = LatestMessage(date: date, isRead: isRead, message: message)
                return Conversation(id: conversationId, latestMessage: latestMessageObject, name: name, otherUserEmail: otherUserEmail)
            }
     }
}
```

in the code below, that's how I call that function which is in another `viewcontroller`
the error is from here `case .failure(let error)`, there's no way the email is wrong, the `safeEmail` is what I expect to be.

```swift
    private func startListeningForConversations(){
        guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as? String else {
            return
        }
        let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(email: email)
        print(safeEmail)
        DatabaseManager.shared.getConversation(with: safeEmail) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
// DatabaseManager is the controller where getConversation function is located
            case .success(let conversations):
                print(conversations)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching conversation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried different methods to parse, but the error is same

code below is what I get in the console after printin `snapshot.value` in `getConversation` function

```swift
Optional({
    id = "conversation_test-mail-ru_test-mail-ru_Mar 1, 2023 at 1:51:21 AM GMT+4";
    "latest_message" =     {
        date = "Mar 1, 2023 at 1:51:21 AM GMT+4";
        "is_read" = 0;
        message = Asdasdasda;
    };
    name = levani;
    "other_user_email" = "test-mail-ru";
})
```

but the error is `Failed to parse conversations`

here's screenshot of my realtime database:

[image]

I even deleted and redownloaded `googleservice-info` file, but still can't parse.
any solution will be appericated

I made `isRead` `Int` because ase you can see in the console log firebase returns `0` instead of `false`

```swift
struct Conversation {
    let id: String
    let latestMessage: LatestMessage
    let name: String
    let otherUserEmail: String
}
struct LatestMessage {
    let date: String
    let isRead: Int
    let message: String
}
```

Comment: You have tried to cast `value` as `[[String:Any]]`, that is an  array of dictionaries. But `value` is not an array as you can see from printing it.  Remove the outermost pair of `[]` from your conditional cast

Comment: I strongly suggest adopting the `Codable` support that Firebase Swift now provides.  It is much simpler to read directly from firebase to your desired structs that's to try and do it manually.

Comment: @Paulw11 I get `Cannot access element using subscript for tuple type 'Dictionary<String, Any>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: Any)'); use '.' notation instead` on every `guard let` statement after removing `[]`

Comment: Yes, because you need to adjust the rest of your code to deal with the fact that it is no longer an array (well, it never was, but your cast said it was). Seriously, use `Codable` and ditch all of this code.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping